# Is it possible to startService in a new thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, service

If I use this piece of code in `onCreate()` MyService will it start in a new thread or will it start in the main thread?

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
    }
});
```

Sorry if it is obvious but I am a beginner in android. I researched a lot and I didn't find anything certain. Thank you

Comment: and the reason you did not tested the code you shown us prior asking, is what exactly?

Comment: This won't event compile since `this` refers to instantiated anonymous  `Runnable` object.

Comment: Sorry! Replace this with MainActivity.this. It is just a simple example to understanding the question. My question is if anybody knows if the service will run in the mayn theread or in this thread?

Answer (score 0):

I hope it runs in UI Thread unless you created a new Thread in Service... but you can conform that Service is running in dfifferent Thread or UI Thread like

start the Service in `onCreate()` of `Activity`

```
    new Thread("myThread"){
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class);
            startService(intent);
        };
    }.start();
```

and test the Thread names in onCreate() of a Service...

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        if(name.equals("myThread")) {
            // service started in new Thread...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: A `Service` will run ONLY in the UI thread. The only exception is `IntentService`

Comment: ok. Thanks. The problem is that I have multiple services which I want to run in a single worker thread. I think that the only possibility is to create a worker thread an use a Handler to pass the tasks to the worker thread.